# Write half-cell reaction for a battery

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, oxidation-state

> A primary battery has the reaction:
> $$\ce{2MnO2 + Zn + 2NH4Cl -> Mn2O3 + Zn(NH3)2Cl2 + H2O}$$
> Write the half-cell reactions for the given equation.

I am having trouble understanding how you know which will be the oxidation reaction and which will be the reduction reaction. From what I have understood I should assign the oxidation states of each reactant and product and from that I assume that the reactions should be:

Ox: $\ce{Zn + 2NH4Cl -> [Zn(NH3)2]^{2+}}$  +  ...

Red:  $\ce{2MnO2 +  ...  -> Mn2O3 + H2O}$  +  ...

And by balancing out the hydrogens and charges I get that:

Ox: $\ce{Zn + 2NH4Cl -> [Zn(NH3)2]^{2+} + 2H+ + 2 Cl- + 2e-}$

Red:  $\ce{2MnO2 + 2H+ + 2e- -> Mn2O3 + H2O}$

Is this correct? Or should the oxidation reaction only be: $\ce{Zn  -> Zn^{2+} + 2e-}$ and then the reduction reaction would consist of the remaining compounds?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Your equation in the question is not balanced by mass, neither oxidation half-reaction.

Comment: @Poutnik Oh, I completely missed the Cl$_2$. 
So then my oxidation reaction would be: Zn+$2$NH$_4$Cl⟶[Zn(NH$_3$)$_2$]$^{+2}$+$2$H$^+$+$2$e$^−$ + $2$Cl$^-$

Comment: @Poutnik Thank you, I didn't know about that notation. But is what I wrote correct?

Comment: @ Katara. Now your equation written with the $2$ chloride ions is correct

Comment: Please fix the equations in your original question, not in the comments.

Comment: The important thing is not us to tell you if what you have written is correct or not. The important is YOU to understand, why it is correct or not. Put in the question why do you think it is or is not correct. BTW equation sides should be either both molecular kind or both ionic kind, not mixed kinds as for the balanced Ox.